# Zendframework and Xampp Installation Problems

Tags: zend-framework, installation, xampp

I am trying to install Zendframework Version 1.11.11 to my PC using Xampp version 3.1.0 3.10 .  When I run the "ZF" command in "cmd" I receive the message "ZF is not a recognized operation.....".

What I tried so far:
Going to my computer properties and changing the path. ;\C:\xampp\php; and \C:\Zend\bin

What else can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to `zf` (to the zf.bat file, to be exact) needs to be in your system path, not in php.ini includes. Refer to [this question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/317631/setting-path-in-windows-7-command-prompt). If your OS is not Win 7, you might need to google for the corretc instructions on setting the path.

Alternatively, you can also use the `zf` command with the full path:

```
C:\xampp\Zend\bin\zf create project myproj
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful. When I ran the command in CMD it said no php.exe found, I basically did the same thing as with the zf.bat and it works.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to have been of help.